# ViewBag property changed to object type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

In my controller i put model object to viewbag as shown in the below:

```
ViewBag.fileModel = new ViewFileModel(id)

public class ViewFileModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public SelectList TrainingSelectList { get; set; }
        public SelectList FileTypeSelectList { get; set; }
        public int trainingId{ get; set; }
        public int fileType { get; set; }

        public ViewFileModel(int employeeId)
        {
            using (var unit = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                Employee = unit.EmployeeRepository.FindBy(e => e.Id == employeeId).SingleOrDefault();
                if (Employee == null)
                {
                    Debug.Print("Employee bulunamadi {0},", employeeId);
                    throw new ArgumentException("Hatali personel parametresi " + employeeId);
                }
                else
                {
                    TrainingSelectList = new SelectList
                       (Employee.TrainingList, "Id", "TrainName");
                    FileTypeSelectList = SelectListUtils.FileTypeSelectList(1);

               }

            }

        }
```

In my view I render partial view and try to pass the object in the view. The passed object will be my new model in the partial view.

```
<div id="employee_files">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsFiles", new { ViewBag.fileModel });
        }
```

At my partial view  i have this : `@model G222.IK.Models.ViewModel.ViewFileModel`

I'm getting the following exception. I think the is problem that ViewBag returns Object and the view is expecting ViewFileModel. I tried to cast it to my model in my renderer view but it did not work. Are there any fix for this?

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'G222.IK.Models.ViewModel.ViewFileModel'.
```

Comment: I would create a strongly typed view instead of using the ViewBag for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a new anonymous object to the partial view.

```
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsFiles", new { ViewBag.fileModel });
```

creates a new object with a property fileModel that has the value of your fileModel object.

You should use:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsFiles", ViewBag.fileModel);
```

that way the value of the ViewBag property will be passed correctly.

Comment: this gives error: Error 2 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<G222.IK.Models.Employee>' has no applicable method named 'RenderPartial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsFiles", ViewBag.fileModel as G222.IK.Models.ViewModel.ViewFileModel);` as the Viewbag is dynamic, you need to cast the object to a proper type before passing it to the method.

Comment: be careful casting, as the mentioned syntax (the `as`) might yield a null value if it can not cast the property.

Comment: can this be the reason i get objectdisposedexception now?

Comment: no. this can happen when you try to use your property after it was disposed. i would suspect the properties to be TrainingSelectList or FileTypeSelectList.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
<div id="employee_files">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsFiles", ViewBag.fileModel);
    }
```